# why the webpack could not found the the module path

Tags: webpack

when I using webpack `webpack 5.82.0` to compile the project:

```
webpack --config webpack.config.js
```

shows error:

```
ERROR in ./src/index.ts 2:0-43
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './component/good/Goods' in '/Users/John/source/reddwarf/frontend/rd-component/src'

ERROR in ./src/index.ts 3:0-38
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './component/pay/Pay' in '/Users/John/source/reddwarf/frontend/rd-component/src'

ERROR in ./src/index.ts 5:0-69
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './component/demo/CommonPageFunction' in '/Users/John/source/reddwarf/frontend/rd-component/src'
```

I have tried to add the module in webpack.config.js like this:

```
resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js'],
    alias: {
      "@": path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
    },
    modules: [
      'node_modules',
      path.resolve(__dirname, 'src')
    ]
  },
```

the index.ts was in the project `projectDir/src/index.ts`. what should I do to fixed this issue? This is the full webpack config:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.ts',
  mode: 'production',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'rd-component.js',
    library: 'rdComponent',
    libraryTarget: 'umd',
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js'],
    alias: {
      "@": path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
    },
    modules: [
      'node_modules',
      path.resolve(__dirname, 'src')
    ]
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        loader: 'ts-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
    ],
  },
};
```